# HUD layer not being added on my scene

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, cclayer

I have a CCScene which already holds my gameLayer and I am trying to add HUD layer on that.But the HUD layer is not getting added in my scene, I can say that because I have set up a CCLabel on HUD layer and when I run my project, I cannot see that label.

Here's what I am doing : 
In my gameLayer:

```
+(id) scene
{

   CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];

   GameScreen *layer = [GameScreen node];
   [scene addChild: layer];

    HUDclass * otherLayer = [HUDclass node];
    [scene addChild:otherLayer];

    layer.HC = otherLayer;// HC is reference to my HUD layer in @Interface of gameLayer
    return scene;
}
```

And then in my HUD layer I have just added a CCLabelTTF in its init method like this :

```
-(id)init {

    if ((self = [super init])) {

    CCLabelTTF * label = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"IN WEAPON CLASS" fontName:@"Arial"    fontSize:15];
     label.position = ccp(240,160);
     [self addChild:label];

    }

    return  self;
}
```

But now when I run my project I dont see that label, What am I doing wrong here ..?

Any Ideas.. ?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1):

hmmm, you are not adding the HUD instance to the scene. try :

```
    HUDclass * otherLayer = [HUDclass node];
    [scene addChild:otherLayer];

    layer.HC = otherLayer;
```

Comment: Its a typing mistake, I might have made when i was posting the question to make it look properly. :) In code I have added  the HUD layer to the scene. 
Thanks for that ! I am repairing it right now.